# Cardinality of the set of injective functions from $A$ to $B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given two infinite sets $A$ and $B$ with $|A|\leq|B|$, determine the cardinality of the set of injective functions from $A$ to $B$.
I think this set has the same cardinality as $B^A$, but I am not sure how to prove it.
Thanks

Comment: "infinte" is a very nice word that could be a typo of both "finite" or "infinite".

Answer (score 3):

The cardinal you are looking for is obviously $\leq B^A$.

To prove it´s $\geq B^A$, notice that as the cardinal of $B$ is the same as the cardinal of $A\times B$, we can find instead the cardinal of the set of injective functions from $A$ to $A\times B$. This is $\geq B^A$ because to each function $f:A\to B$ you can assign the injective function $f':A\to A\times B; a\mapsto(a,f(a))$, and obviously if $f$ and $g$ are different, $f'$ and $g'$ are different.

Comment: Great, thank you